# How can I get public key of author certificate in tizen werable web app?

Tags: android, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app, tizen-studio

In my **tizen werable web application** (target: **tizen 2.3.2**) I need to get public key of author certificate (used for sign app) for check token of paired smartphone app in **SAP** [*Samsung Accessory Protocol*] authentication implementation.

Werable app and smartphone app (android) are signed with same keystore.

Is it possible via packageManager API or similar?

```
var myAppSigCert = "";//I NEED THIS ONE

SAAgent.authenticatePeerAgent(peerAgent,
    function(peerAgent, authToken){
        if (authToken.key === myAppSigCert ) {
            alert("Service connection request accepted: " + peerAgent.appName);
            SAAgent.acceptServiceConnectionRequest(peerAgent);      
        }else{
            alert("Service connection request REJECT: " + peerAgent.appName);
            SAAgent.rejectServiceConnectionRequest(peerAgent);
        }
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found. First of all in **config.xml** of web application add **CERTIFICATE** privilege:

```
    <tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/appmanager.certificate"/>
```

Then simply call **getAppCert** method of **tizen.application**:

```
var appCerts = tizen.application.getAppCerts(null);
for (var i = 0; i < appCerts.length; i++) {
    console.log("#" + i + " type:" + appCerts[i].type);
    console.log("#" + i + " value:" + appCerts[i].value);
}
```

**appmanager.certificate** privilege need signing **AuthorCertificate** of **PARTNER** level to be used, for **PUBLIC** **AuthorCertificate** it return this exception during app installation:

```
-   [MISMATCHED_PRIVILEGE_LEVEL]Signature Level is too low to use http://tizen.org/privilege/appmanager.certificate - Signature Level = public, Privilege Level = partner
```

**More info about Tizen privileges are available here:**
https://www.tizen.org/tv/privilege

**Info about privileges security system:**
https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.4/org.tizen.gettingstarted/html/web/details/sec_privileges_w.htm

**API reference to get Public Key of signing certificates at runtime:** https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/web-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.3.2/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/device_api/wearable/tizen/application.html#ApplicationManager::getAppCerts

Answer (score -1):

Author certificates helps in maintaining secure peer authentication between the Tizen Gear App and the Android
mobile app. The Certificate Extension SDK support creation of Tizen author certificate based on Android keystore file.

Tutorial for [Creating Gear Author Certificate Using
Android Keystore](http://developer.samsung.com/html/techdoc/ProgrammingGuide_Accessory.pdf) >> **Appendix D**

[image]

After creating the certificate you may find the public key of author certificate from your machine,

```
/tizen-sdk-data/keystore/author-name/author
```

Use it in your code like

```
// from sample app
var authTokenKey = "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAhO5x67wRt3Ni5A4n+HBbAczE6p8lAEgnywXInIUMKuCDSaEpM3EwYE6GUGACDbAoCx7EBTS54XbLWrnz10XZAKZyMoQidI+JWiSwlNYOxGlfHJgxVEExr2ZmlKVYedQxlGZNsLjGziYW0Y6UIXmDOeDA1b4g7Grbx0vS1BXC3Mv8s/8zlAl3NPj6BU1mh2hWKJL9+eDaM3bmYK1JJ9jbLlIzCsl0fZ4kR1xlSToZDBk53LxO0n1ekUpsEmMbFcmj1KKGQQn6A+ej0s5iOlXz6dgDfg4PxoTnlutwLOilz4zJLySZA6o3jG2kYls6ZBEjaz9ZeHxQlEV9PKh/Vgq8wwIDAQAB"

    /* Authentication of requesting peer agent */
    if (typeof(SAAgent.authenticatePeerAgent) === 'function') {
        SAAgent.authenticatePeerAgent(
            peerAgent,
            function (peerAgent, authToken) {
                /* Authentication token of peer agent arrives */
                if (authToken.key === authTokenKey) {
                    SAAgent.acceptServiceConnectionRequest(peerAgent);
                    createHTML("Service connection request accepted via authenticatePeerAgent");

                } else {
                    SAAgent.rejectServiceConnectionRequest(peerAgent);
                    createHTML("Service connection request rejected via authenticatePeerAgent");
                }
            },
            function (e) {
                /* Error handling */
                SAAgent.rejectServiceConnectionRequest(peerAgent);
                createHTML("Service connection request rejected due to error:<br />" +
                            "Error name : " + e.name + "<br />" +
                            "Error message : " + e.message);
            }
        );
    }
```

Find  the [sample app](http://developer.samsung.com/gear/develop/samples/companion/security-web) of SAP.

Comment: There is a way to get "authTokenKey" via API at runtime instead of manually set that?

Comment: From where it will find the Key at the runtime ?

Comment: From tizen watch app (web), in android smartphone app i'm able to get public key of signing certificate, my question is if in tizen web sdk exist any API to get public key  without manually set that in a javascript variable, for example  [packageManagerAPI](https://developer.tizen.org/zh-hans/development/guides/web-application/application-management/package-information) You know a way?

Comment: Can you please check if you still have the "Advanced options"? My Certificate Manager doesn't have that option, so I can't sign the Tizen app with the same as the Android. Therefore I cannot secure the communication, it would be a great help if you could check your Certificate Manager.